# I made both of you buy the (games or game)

Tags: grammatical-number, distributive-determiners

I had made two of my friends buy CS:GO and today, while texting in a group I said "I made both of you buy the games". My friend corrected me with "*game". Was I wrong? I tried googling but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I think this Q is different enough not to be a duplicate. This question concerns a retail purchase, and the language of trading tends to have its own rules. This Q also has a *both* in it, which further muddies the waters. The actual word that could optionally be pluralized in this sentence has been elided -  a copy/copies.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say your friend was correct. There is only one game: CS:GO. There are two purchases of the game which is made quite clear in your sentence. Had you made your friends buy CS:GO and chess then "I made both of you buy the games" seems correct.

Comment: But let's take a different situation. Let's say I've made them buy a car. Then I'd have to say "I made both of you buy the car". Then let's say I've made each of them buy different cars, then would it still be "I made both of the buy the car"? Can you check out the duplicates and get back to me? They seem quite relevant

Comment: Could we please put ourselves in a different situation? Let’s say you’ve made each of Janet and John ask different Questions, then would it still be *you made both of the ask the Question?*

Either way, can you bring your*self* to check out the duplicates, somewhere such as English Language Learners, and get back to ELL? They seem quite straightforward.

Comment: @AkshayNagraj for the different models I would say "I made both of you buy a car". "the car" implies there really is only one.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I would say "ask the Question" implies there is only one question. In the OP there are two physical purchases but of only one game, hence "both of you buy the game" seems correct.

Comment: Rob, it is and it isn’t but that’s as much the nature of the Question as of the language. Akshay’s friend was clearly correct, so I upvoted your Answer. That clarity was *as asked* though.

Go with a buddy to a dealership selling bikes as well as cars and let the sales guy talk you both into buying cars.

May he not then say *I made both of you buy the car*? I think that stretch becomes too long only if you buy different models.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I can imagine he may say that - although when pushed he would probably admit that by saying 'buy the car' he was referring to the model rather than the physical cars they will get. I may be trying to fit angels on pins though.

Comment: Rob, that's exactly what I meant… more generic even than the model, the car which in this case happens to stand for the idea of cars as opposed to bikes. So yes, the model rather than the physical cars, just as originally the game rather than the physical copies…